# How to solve the consumption matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, random-matrices

There are three industries interrelated so that their outputs are used as inputs by themselves.

$$
A \;\; =\;\; [a_{jk}] \;\; = \;\; \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
0.1 & 0.5 & 0 \\
0.8 & 0 & 0.4 \\
0.1 & 0.5 & 0.6 \\
\end{array} \right ]
$$

Here

1. $a_{jk}$ is the fraction of the output of industry $k$ consumed by industry $j$.
2. $p_j$ be the price charged by industry $j$ for its total output.

A problem is to find prices so that for each industry, total expenditures equal total income. Show that this leads to $Ap = p$, where $p = \left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
p_1&  p_2 &  p_3\\
\end{array} \right ]$, and find a solution $p$ with nonnegative $p_1, p_2, p_3$. Also, show that the consumption matrix $A$ must have columns which sum to $1$ and always has eigenvalue $1$. What approach should I follow to solve this question.?

Answer (score 1):

Solving the equation $Ap = p$, you are looking for an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$, so the null space of $A - I$ should provide you with adequate vectors. To prove that $1$ is always an eigenvalue, first realize that $\det A = \det A^T$, which leads to the fact that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues. It is easily proven for a **left stochastic matrix** (note that these follow the exact same form as your consumption matrix) such as $A$ that the following vector $\vec{u} =\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$ is *always* an eigenvector of $A^T$ corresponding to $\lambda = 1$ (see below). Consequently, $1$ must also be an eigenvalue of $A$.
$$A^T\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0.1 & 0.8 &0.1 \\0.5 & 0 & 0.5 \\0.6 & 0.4 &0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\1 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks @Hyperion.